# Is it possible to use Clojurescript or Google Closure to write Chrome extensions or web app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, clojure, google-closure, clojurescript

I want to use clojurescript to write chrome extensions.

Answer (score 23):

Chrome extensions are generally made with HTML/CSS/JS so ClojureScript should work just fine because it compiles to JavaScript.  That being said, I don't think anyone has actually built a large extension with ClojureScript yet.  As a proof of concept here's a general outline of how to make a simple alert extension that will say Zaboomafoo (sorry for that name):

Install [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) and [lein-cljsbuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild) first.  Read the docs for lein-cljsbuild and check out the [wiki on ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki) to understand how to use lein-cljsbuild for projects and compiling.

Make a ClojureScript file that displays an alert saying "Zaboomafoo" like this:

```
(ns Zaboomafoo.hello)   
(js/alert "Zaboomafoo")
```

Compile this with `lein cljsbuild` to get a JavaScript file.  Then add a basic HTML file and manifest.json for the extension.

Zaboomafoo.html:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Zaboomafoo!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Zaboomafoo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
   "name": "Displays Zaboomafoo when opening a new tab",
   "version": "0.1",
   "incognito": "split",
   "chrome_url_overrides": {
   "newtab": "Zaboomafoo.html"
  },
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Put the new manifest.json, Zaboomafoo.html, and Zaboomafoo.js into a folder somewhere obvious.  Finally, go to the chrome extension page, turn on developer mode, load unpacked extension, and open a new tab.  The extension should load an alert that annoyingly says "Zaboomafoo" when you open the tab.  Hopefully making browser extensions gets to be a little more popular but this is the general flow of it.

Answer (score 8):

I have just released a simple Chrome extension sample project along with some documentation:
https://github.com/binaryage/chromex-sample

It uses Chromex library:
https://github.com/binaryage/chromex

Disclaimer: I'm author of the library

Answer (score 0):

I started [this](https://github.com/marcelocra/chrome-extension-cljs-example) project with the exact purpose of writing a Chrome extension using ClojureScript.

While `greenyouse` answer does provide you the general directions, as a beginner in ClojureScript I had some trouble using `lein` and `cljsbuild` and chose to go for the basic setup first. Maybe it will help someone.

Sidenote: I plan to migrate my project to `lein` and `cljsbuild` once I understant things better. At that point I'll update this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this](http://clockwork-fig.blogspot.in/2012/01/clojure-extension-for-chrome.html) chrome extension written in cljs which allows you to eval clojure code in browser by selection as an example.

Comment: It seems like this project (goranjovic/chromeclojure) doesn't use any ClojureScript. Rather the Chrome extension (written in plain JavaScript) sends selected Clojure code to an external Clojure JVM process and returns the result to the browser. I don't think this is really what the poster was looking for.